# Contact Us thank you message

Tags: interaction-design, contact-us

we currently have a contact us page that allows visitors to send an email to us through it, would it be a good idea to also send an email to the visitor thanking him for the message to let him know it was sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you provide confirmation on-page as soon as they have submitted the form, then you don't need to send the email. Typically, confirmation emails may infer that a ticket of some sort has been opened. From this email, the user can see a ticket # and can respond.

Answer (score 1):

As far as you showing an alert with a thank you message on submit of form no need to send an email.

Reasons:
1- Email gets ignored
2- I personally don't like to receive an email for a thank you message
3- you need to develop a mail template which can increase time and cost.

You can send a reply email based on the query submitted by the client and in that you can add a Thank you message.

Answer (score 1):

A follow up email may be considered spam, but as others have said, you **should** provide feedback as to the state of the action within your site.

Some suggestions for the feedback:

- The feedback should inform the user what happened (e.g. an email was sent to us, and probably thank them for their time/effort)
- The feedback should set the users expectation (e.g. you will receive a reply within 24 hours)
- The feedback should let to user what to do next (e.g. Go back to their task, display a relevant CTA etc)

There's probably more, but those would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

In-page feedback and thank you message is absolutely necessary.

Regarding a possible email, rather than a thank you note, you could let the user decide if they want to receive a copy of their message at their email address. It's both a confirmation that their message has been sent and a copy for their own record that they might find useful (depending on the type of website and message they send).